powershell alternative for JQ command
I am trying to retrieve secrets from github , via github actions workflow
So, I am using toJSON context to set the env context in SECRETS
and looping through secret values $secret = "SEC1, SEC2 "
I have the below in bash and I need help with powershell alterative for the below command
value="$(jq -r --arg key "$secret" '.[$key]' <<< "$SECRETS" | sed 's|.|& |g')"

I tried the below
$value = ( jq -r --arg key $value '.[$key]' | $env:SECRETS ) -replace '(.)', '$1 '

But i get
= ( jq -r --arg key $value '.[$key]' | $env:SECRETS ) -repl …
   |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
   | Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.


What's the point of using PowerShell if you're not using what it has to offer? If env:secrets is a json string then you can use ConvertFrom-Json and end up with an object you can easily work with.

$env:SECRETS | jq ?

why use jq? PowerShell already has the ability to convert from various data formats directly into PowerShell objects. jq is only necessary in other text-based shells

Thnk you guys, i was able to use the powershell ConvertFrom-Json to fetch the secrets
